How to store jwt token in Chrome local storage for a chrome extension?
I have written a chrome extension login.html that acts as popup on the screen. It has an email and password form and a sign in button.
I have a login.js that has an event listener to check when the 'Sign In' button is clicked. It will then trigger a POST API request that I have made using fastAPI which returns: {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
I am trying to send the access-token to local storage but I am not able to see it.
Im able to see a success message that the login is successful and in vs code I can see that the login request was successful:
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64482 - "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
I have tried this login.js:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        console.log("testing console log")
        // Retrieve the API URL from chrome.storage.local and store it in localStorage
        chrome.storage.local.get(['apiURL'], function(result) {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.error('Error retrieving API URL:', chrome.runtime.lastError);
            } else {
                const apiUrl = result.apiURL;
                console.log('Retrieved API URL:', apiUrl);
                // Use the API URL as needed
                localStorage.setItem('apiUrl', apiUrl);
            }
        });

        // Add event listener for when user clicks submit
        const loginForm = document.querySelector('form');  
        const messageDiv = document.createElement('div');
        loginForm.parentElement.appendChild(messageDiv);

        loginForm.addEventListener('submit', async function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // Retrieve API URL from localStorage
            const apiUrl = localStorage.getItem('apiUrl');
            if (!apiUrl) {
                console.error('API URL not found in localStorage');
                return;
            }

            const email = loginForm.querySelector('input[type="email"]').value;
            const password = loginForm.querySelector('input[type="password"]').value;
            const loginUrl = `${apiUrl}/login`;  

            try {
                const response = await fetch(loginUrl, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    body: new URLSearchParams({
                        username: email,  
                        password: password
                    })
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
                }

                // Add jwt to local storage
                const data = await response.json();
                const accessToken = data.access_token;
                console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken);

                messageDiv.classList.remove('d-none', 'alert-danger');
                messageDiv.classList.add('alert', 'alert-success');
                messageDiv.innerText = 'Login successful!';
                
                setTimeout(() => {
                    window.close();
                }, 2000);

            } catch (error) {
                messageDiv.classList.remove('d-none', 'alert-success');
                messageDiv.classList.add('alert', 'alert-danger');
                messageDiv.innerText = error.message;
            }
    });`

Working:

Post request is being sent

Issues:
1)
 console.log("testing console log") 


this is not being logged to console




 console.log('Access Token:', accessToken); 


this is not being logged to console




localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken); 


this is not being stored in local storage


none of those console.log's occur ... conclusion: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' isn't being fired, probably because the page is already loaded - the rest of the issues are obvious if that event handler doesn't ever run

It was working correctly. I was checking the active tab console rather than the pop up console.
